# Split a IN condition in a Oracle query string

Tags: c#, string, oracle, split

In my Silverlight application, I use a tool to generate reports. I create the reports in a standalone application using Oracle queries and then I render it in my application.

On a report, I can set multi-values filters, for example a list of categories, and I use it in a IN condition in my query :

```
WHERE IDCATEGORY IN(:CategoryFilter)
```

The problem is that if my filter has more than 1000 values, I get an error ("ORA-01795 :the number of values in a "IN" cannot be greater than 1000. )

I have access to the query before it is executed, so I could split my IN conditions with a String.Replace.... Or is there an alternative to IN that work with more than 1000 values ?

Any idea how to do it ?

Example, from :

```
"...WHERE IDCATEGORY IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...,999,1001, 1002, 1003)..."
```

To :

```
"...WHERE IDCATEGORY IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...,999,1000) OR IN (1001, 1002, 1003)..."
```

Comment: I think that the simplest approach to try is:
1. Create (or clear) temp table for IDs
2. Insert the IDs
3. Use join from target table to temp in place of IN clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My parameter is simply a string like "1,2,3,4,5". Can I create a temp table from it ?

Comment: That is not an answer - just a suggestion. I am sure there is no difficulty in splitting, parsing and inserting of "1, 2", but there can be a big concurrency problem with temp table(when there are two or more queries clearing and filling it at the same time), so you will have to somehow uniquely identify data for each request (possibly with another column containing unique request ID).